# Colour number of days field on report based on overdue date

Tags: reporting

I have a report on opportunities showing the open opportunities.
I did a row-field formula to calculate the number days they're overdue based on their estimated due date.

In the report, I'd love to have all the fields coloured a different colour when the days are under 90 days, between 90 days and 180 days and when they are over 180.

I've looked at conditional formatting but it only does it on Subtotals and I want colour at row level, on individual fields. Is it possible? And how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a basic tool that would do that in a report.

But if you want to color-code the report, you could take a different approach. Instead of using the report record-level formula, create a new Formula (Text) field on the Contact. Before doing that, upload three small images of red/yellow/green color blocks. Reference them in the conditions of your formula, and they will appear instead of text. Not perfect, but close.